# Flutter: Build linux desktop without View

Tags: linux, flutter

I am trying to achive "service" like behavior.
So i want to build my app without any view.
Or maybe only to have option to run it without view so it can run in envirment that not suport UI like a cloud.

Any ideas how can i achive this?

Comment: simply add your code in `main()` function without any `runApp(...)`

Comment: Even so you still have the flutter generated view. So basically you will have a window with white screen.

Comment: so write everything in pure dart: no flutter at all